# first_or_initialize is not working for relative model and creating new record each time

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

```
ccs.each do |cd|
  relative_model = main_model.relative_model.where(start_date: XYZ, end_date: XYZ).first_or_initialize
  relative_model.capacity = cd['capacity'].to_f
  relative_model.save!
end
```

As per above code, first_or_initialize is not working for relative model and creating new record each time.

Here is the query run at background for both inr:

```
SELECT `capacity_commitments`.* FROM `capacity_commitments`  WHERE `capacity_commitments`.`participants_subscription_id` = 1 AND `capacity_commitments`.`start_date` = '2016-11-16' AND `capacity_commitments`.`end_date` = '2016-11-21'

SELECT `capacity_commitments`.* FROM `capacity_commitments`  WHERE `capacity_commitments`.`participants_subscription_id` = 1 AND `capacity_commitments`.`start_date` = '2016-11-16' AND `capacity_commitments`.`end_date` = '2016-11-21'
```

NEED INITIAL HELP OR POINT OUT WHAT IS WRONG IN ABOVE CODE?

Comment: Maybe the way you are passing date doesn't match with the record in db? Can you provide close-to-real query?

Comment: @archana these two record actually executing {"program_identifier"=>"test_program_1", "start_date"=>"2016-11-16", "end_date"=>"2016-11-21", "capacity"=>"123.45"}         
X2: {"program_identifier"=>"test_program_1", "start_date"=>"2016-11-16", "end_date"=>"2016-11-21", "capacity"=>"234.56"}

Comment: have you encountered any errors?

Comment: @illusionist its not about error, its about create a new record while we expect the update the existing one.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use find_or_initialize_by method

```
relative_model =  main_model.relative_model.find_or_initialize_by(start_date: XYZ, end_date: XYZ)
```

Comment: Rails 4 support find_or_initialize_by?

Comment: check http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/find_or_initialize_by

Comment: what if we have multiple record and using find?

Comment: we need to iterate first and then apply find_or_initialize_by

Comment: @Pratap That's really non-optimal solution, `first_or_initialize` should work.